# What the actual is going on with C# structs?

Tags: c#

So its pretty simple issue

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct test
{
    public uint a;
}
```

^ This marshals to size of 4

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct test
{
    public IntPtr b;
}
```

^ This marshals to size of 8

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct test
{
    public uint a;
    public IntPtr b;
}
```

^ This marshals to size of 16

Now I'm not sure if my calculator is broken or something but I'm pretty sure 8+4 isnt 16..... Is there any reason this nonsense is taking place?

I need it to produce the correct size for use with windows API calls

Well I'm trying to call "NtQueryInformationThread" and my struct is invalid for that here is the structure:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TbiClientId
    {
        public IntPtr UniqueProcess;
        public IntPtr UniqueThread;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ThreadBasicInformation
    {
        public uint ExitStatus;
        public IntPtr TebBaseAdress;
        public int ProcessId;
        public TbiClientId ClientId;
        public UIntPtr AffinityMask;
        public uint Priority;
        public uint BasePriority;
    }
```

Under marshal.sizeof this comes out as 56 yet the API only accepts 48 if I pass 48 to the API it returns a success and fills the struct....

Comment: The compiler uses alignment.

Comment: 16 is the correct size for winapi calls.  Google "structure member alignment" and "structlayoutattribute.pack" to learn more.

Comment: Correct maybe but NtQueryInformationThread is not accepting 56 of the marshal size... only 48 as which is the number of my struct values directly. When I add "Pack = 1" to the struct then its accepted is this API just odd?

Comment: Not a duplicate of the question marked duplicate. Related topic, answers cover a lot of the same points, but very different questions.

Comment: int ProcessId is not actually present in this undocumented struct.  Delete it and you'll get 48.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `uint` is a 32-bit type.
An `IntPtr` is platform-dependent, and will be 64-bit on 64-bit platforms.

For the 3rd example, struct members are aligned to certain boundaries to make memory access more efficient, which in this case appears to be on 8-byte boundaries. You can modify this using [the `Pack` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=net-5.0).

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct test
{
    public uint a;
    public IntPtr b;
}
```